# Regex to match both domain and subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pattern-matching

Say I want to see if an email matches nabisco.com or a subdomain of nabisco.com, such as x.nabisco.com.

So we have this:

```
/.+@.*nabisco\.com$/.test(email)
```

but the problem with this regex, is that it would admit emails like this:

```
bar@foonabisco.com
```

but we need to limit it to

```
bar@foo.nabisco.com
```

how can I make the first . character required, conditional on the presence of a subdomain?

**The problem is that this regex also needs to match bar@nabisco.com, with no subdomain.**

Comment: Just add `\.` - `/.+@.*\.nabisco\.com$/.test(email)`

Comment: sorry, I was unclear, I also need to match bar@nabisco.com, with no subdomain :) that's the trick

Comment: Maybe `[.@]nabisco\.com$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/.+@(.*\.)?nabisco\.com$/.test(email)
```

This should do it.

#### [*How it works*](https://regex101.com/r/TxobuL/2)

With the addition of `(.*\.)?` you assert that anything before `nabisco` has to be succeeded by a `.`. The `?` after the parenthesis specifies that either the whole part (say `foo.` matches) or none of it matches (so foonabisco will not match).

If you don't want to match something like `test@foo.bar.nabisco.com`, then your regex should be `/.+@(.*?\.)?nabisco\.com$/`.

Comment: thanks can you explain a bit how the conditional works?

Comment: what is this doing:  (.*\.)?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've edited my answer. Also, just a quick question. Is something like `test@foo.bar.naibisco.com` also valid?

Comment: yeah that's valid, as long as it ends with either @nabisco.com or .nabisco.com

Comment: @AlexanderMills In that case you're good to go with the first regex.

Comment: superb thank you very much, once proven will accept answer

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've made your work easy for you. Go ahead and click the link above. Will take you to a demo. :) Stole the demo link from Jan, so thanks to them.

Comment: nice, yeah I have used that site before, it is beautiful

Answer (score 2):

You could use a solution with a pos. lookahead:

```
(?=.*\bnabisco\b)\S*@\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/TxobuL/1/).

---

This will look for `nabisco` with word boundaries on both sides, so the following will be matched:

```
bar@foo.nabisco.com
bar@nabisco.com
```

While these won't:

```
bar@foonabisco.com
nabisco
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regular expression pattern

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/[.a-z]+\.domain\.com[.a-z0-9/-]+/
```

it might help you